# How to recieve email from Contact Us from written with Flask

Tags: email, flask, server, web-deployment, web-hosting

I just created a *Contact Us* form using Flask. The code seems to work correclty as explained in many tutorials like this one: [link](http://https:/https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982).

The reason why it all works it is because at the beginning of the app file I need to insert the username and password of the person who is sending the mail (in this case it's me) through the form:

```
mail = Mail()
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'my_personal_email0@gmail.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'my_personal_password'
mail.init_app(app)
```

However once my website will be hosted online in some server, whoever wants to contact me trhough the form will just have the option to insert his email in the form and of course no password. Here it is what it looks like:

[image]

Would you be able to explain how this situation is handle once I host the website in some server? Is there something wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things here

1. You need to store the details in the database and make an admin panel to view the details from the database
2. Create a fake Gmail and let that Gmail send you the users name, email subject, and message

I personally prefer the 1st option

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not sure whether your answer is related to my problem. The issue is that as long I am working on my local machine I am the one writing to myself and therefore know app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"]  and 
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] in advance. However once I go live, it will be other people like you that want to contact me through the form. Based on what you wrote you are assuming I  also know your personal password which is not the case.

Comment: @FedericoGentile Those credentails are used by your app to authenticate with the SMTP server.  If they work locally they will also work on the live server.  What Gaurav suggests is setting up a dedicated email account whose creds can be used for your app. If you're using Flask-Mail it [provides the ability](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#sending-messages) to supply a `sender` argument when creating a `Message`.  For this you could provide the `Your Email` value from the form.  However this might not play nice with some SMTP servers.

Comment: @v25 yes, Create a dedicated email for your app, or create an admin panel, what do you prefer?